# onRequestPermissionsResult() does not finish before onViewCreated() conduct

Tags: android-fragments, permissions, request

public class PdfRendererBasicFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

```
/**
 * Key string for saving the state of current page index.
 */
private static final String STATE_CURRENT_PAGE_INDEX = "current_page_index";
public static final int EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 2;

/**
 * File descriptor of the PDF.
 */


/**
 * {@link android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer} to render the PDF.
 */
private PdfRenderer mPdfRenderer;

/**
 * Page that is currently shown on the screen.
 */
private PdfRenderer.Page mCurrentPage;

/**
 * {@link android.widget.ImageView} that shows a PDF page as a {@link android.graphics.Bitmap}
 */
private ImageView mImageView;

/**
 * {@link android.widget.Button} to move to the previous page.
 */
private Button mButtonPrevious;

/**
 * {@link android.widget.Button} to move to the next page.
 */
private Button mButtonNext;


private Bundle copySavedInstanceState;


public PdfRendererBasicFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pdf_renderer_basic, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // Retain view references.
    mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    mButtonPrevious = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.previous);
    mButtonNext = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.next);
    // Bind events.
    mButtonPrevious.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButtonNext.setOnClickListener(this);
    mImageView.setOnClickListener(this);

    copySavedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;


    while (true) {

        int rc = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (rc == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            break;
    }
    // Show the first page by default.
    int index = 0;
    // If there is a savedInstanceState (screen orientations, etc.), we restore the page index.
    if (null != copySavedInstanceState) {
        index = copySavedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_CURRENT_PAGE_INDEX, 0);
    }

    Log.d("check","index : " + index);

    showPage(index);


}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    int rc = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (rc == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        try {
            openRenderer(activity);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Error! " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            activity.finish();
        }
    } else {
        requestExternalStoragePermission();
    }
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    try {
        closeRenderer();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onDetach();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (null != mCurrentPage) {
        outState.putInt(STATE_CURRENT_PAGE_INDEX, mCurrentPage.getIndex());
    }
}

private void requestExternalStoragePermission() {

    final String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

    if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), permissions, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        return;
    }

    final Activity thisActivity = getActivity();

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity, permissions,
                    EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    };

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode != EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Got unexpected permission result: " + requestCode);
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        return;
    }

    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Camera permission granted - initialize the camera source");

        // we have permission, so can read SD Card now.
        try {
            openRenderer(getActivity());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error! " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getActivity().finish();
        }

        return;
    }

    Log.e("TAG", "Permission not granted: results len = " + grantResults.length +
            " Result code = " + (grantResults.length > 0 ? grantResults[0] : "(empty)"));

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        }
    };

}

/**
 * Sets up a {@link android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer} and related resources.
 */
private void openRenderer(Context context) throws IOException {

    File file = new File("/sdcard/Download/test.pdf");
    mPdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));


}

/**
 * Closes the {@link android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer} and related resources.
 *
 * @throws java.io.IOException When the PDF file cannot be closed.
 */
private void closeRenderer() throws IOException {
    if (null != mCurrentPage) {
        mCurrentPage.close();
    }
    mPdfRenderer.close();

}

/**
 * Shows the specified page of PDF to the screen.
 *
 * @param index The page index.
 */
private void showPage(int index) {
    if (mPdfRenderer.getPageCount() <= index) {
        return;
    }
    // Make sure to close the current page before opening another one.
    if (null != mCurrentPage) {
        mCurrentPage.close();
    }
    // Use `openPage` to open a specific page in PDF.
    mCurrentPage = mPdfRenderer.openPage(index);
    // Important: the destination bitmap must be ARGB (not RGB).
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mCurrentPage.getWidth(), mCurrentPage.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    // Here, we render the page onto the Bitmap.
    // To render a portion of the page, use the second and third parameter. Pass nulls to get
    // the default result.
    // Pass either RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY or RENDER_MODE_FOR_PRINT for the last parameter.
    mCurrentPage.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
    // We are ready to show the Bitmap to user.
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    updateUi();
}

/**
 * Updates the state of 2 control buttons in response to the current page index.
 */
private void updateUi() {
    int index = mCurrentPage.getIndex();
    int pageCount = mPdfRenderer.getPageCount();
    mButtonPrevious.setEnabled(0 != index);
    mButtonNext.setEnabled(index + 1 < pageCount);
    getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name_with_index, index + 1, pageCount));
}

/**
 * Gets the number of pages in the PDF. This method is marked as public for testing.
 *
 * @return The number of pages.
 */
public int getPageCount() {
    return mPdfRenderer.getPageCount();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.previous: {
            // Move to the previous page
            showPage(mCurrentPage.getIndex() - 1);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.next: {
            // Move to the next page
            Log.d("name", mCurrentPage.getIndex() + "");
            showPage(mCurrentPage.getIndex() + 1);
            break;

        }
        case R.id.image: {
            Log.d("name", mCurrentPage.getIndex() + "");
            break;
        }


    }
}
```

}

HI, this is my code.

I try to fix. but it's not going well.

problem is this.

When I conduct this app. Android request permission, and I Approve.

but at that time android perform 'onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)' method before 'openRenderer(activity)' is done.
so 'showPage(index)' raise some error. and after then (I mean permission already approved, and execute again) app doing well.

but I want to fix that.

I think

At the first time, onAttach(Activity activity) execute
and after permission approved, 
onAttach(Activity activity) and 
onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
methods seems to run at the same time.

Please advice me.

Thank you.

Comment: I try to locate showPage(index); after openRenderer(activity);

Comment: but it's not working.

Comment: Turn's out. onRequestPermissionsResult didn't call. I will check why.

Comment: onRequestPermissionsResult doesn't call because I used ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity, permissions,
                    EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

Comment: Use requestPermissions(permissions,
                    EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

Comment: then onRequestPermissionsResult  called. but still onViewCreated called first

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // Retain view references.
    Log.d("timeStamp", "onViewCreated ");
    mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    mButtonPrevious = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.previous);
    mButtonNext = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.next);
    // Bind events.
    mButtonPrevious.setOnClickListener(this);
    mButtonNext.setOnClickListener(this);
    mImageView.setOnClickListener(this);


    Log.d("timeStamp", "onViewCreated 할당완료");


    while (true) {
        int rc = getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (rc == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            try {
                openRenderer(getActivity());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error! " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getActivity().finish();
            }
            break;
        }


        Log.d("timeStamp", "얼마나 기다리는겨");
    }


    // Show the first page by default.
    int index = 0;
    // If there is a savedInstanceState (screen orientations, etc.), we restore the page index.
    if (null != savedInstanceState) {
        index = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_CURRENT_PAGE_INDEX, 0);
    }

    Log.d("timeStamp", "showPage 호출 직전");

    showPage(index);


}
```

}

I avoid this problem to add this code.

```
 while (true) {
    int rc = getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (rc == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        try {
            openRenderer(getActivity());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error! " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
        break;
    }


    Log.d("timeStamp", "얼마나 기다리는겨");
}
```

but. this is not a best.

I figured this happen because  onAttach method call requestPermissions method and end. onViewCreated start before User answer to request and onRequestPermissionsResult called (So openRenderer start).

So I suspend showPage method until PERMISSION_GRANTED.